# Tsql getting depending data over multiple rows in one query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to calculate an average of a value in one year. I have a historical data table that saves the changes of the value in time.
I know how to do this with a (sub)query for each individual month, but Im hopeful that there is a simple way to do it in one query.

Example:

```
   ID, Value, DateUntilActivity
   1, 10.00, 2014-03-01
   2, 5.00, 2014-05-01
   3, 3.00, 2014-07-01
   4, 12.00, 2014-10-01
```

So - the correct calculation here is:

```
(2x10.00 + 2x5.00 + 2x3.00 + 3x12.00 + 3x<current_value_in_a_different_table>)/12
```

The calculation includes the number of moths the data was active for - the first value, 10.00 was valid in 2 months - January and February.
And consider the value current_value_in_a_different_table a fixed value.

Also, it needs to work on MSSQL server 2005.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The SUM command will get you a total value of a numeric column as part of a query. But why do you multiply each value?

Comment: I have to calculate an average through the whole year - the first value 10.00 - it hase the date 2014-03-01 - so that means it was an active value for 2 whole months - january and february.

Comment: Ah right. Bang goes the simple solution I was working on. You might want to edit the question to make that clearer - and also where this other value in a different table is coming from.

Comment: Is this all the data you've got, or does each row have a unique ID?

Comment: Yes, it has a unique ID, will edit. But I cant rely on the correct order of IDs in correlation to DateUntilActivity - the DateUntilActivitiy is an editable column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with cte as 
(
    select value, DateUntilActivity from yourtable
    union
    select 100 as currentvalue, '2015-1-1' from yourothertable
)
select avg(value)
from
(
    select (select top 1 value from cte where DateUntilActivity>DATEADD(MONTH,number, '2014-1-1') order by DateUntilActivity ) as value
    from master..spt_values 
    where type='p' and number <=11
) v
```

If my memory is wrong and you can't use a CTE, this is equivalent to

```
select avg(value)
from
(
    select 
        (select top 1 value 
            from 
            (
                            select value, DateUntilActivity from yourtable
                            union
                            select 100 as currentvalue, '2015-1-1' from yourothertable
            ) v 
            where DateUntilActivity>DATEADD(MONTH,number, '2014-1-1') order by DateUntilActivity ) as value
    from master..spt_values 
    where type='p' and number <=11
) v
```

Comment: Was trying to do something similar, but you beat me to it :) However, the question has now changed to specify SQL 2005, where CTE's aren't allowed :(

Comment: @MattThrower I think they were http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175972(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you podiluska. Will try it.

Comment: I've searched a bit about master..spt_values, since I've never used it, and there is quite a debate aboute it, is there another way to do the cte without it?

Comment: @user1659425 Yes. Just create a table with numbers 0 to 11 in it.